# Extract information from a HTTP URL/link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to implement a card that has a link inside:

Example link: https://github.com/ricokahler/next-data-hooks

How can I get this link's image preview and metadata to display it on the UI?

If I paste this link on Facebook or an app like discord/slack, it will show an image + metadata preview
[image]

I found this library which is almost identical to my needs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-preview-js

Can someone explain how to make this custom to avoid using the library?

Comment: `fetch` the URL, parse the result, then look for the <meta> tags. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fricokahler%2Fnext-data-hooks